# How to retrieve a list/result from a QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using Query DSL with version 4.0.4 here's my dependencies;

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and Here's a snippet of my QueryDSL query.

```
        JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
        QQuotation quotation = QQuotation.quotation;
        query.from(quotation).where(quotation.ticketNumber.like("this"))
```

However the query method doesn't have a list() method
        when I line  `.where(quotation.ticketNumber.like("this"))`

Here's the full code.

```
import com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLQuery;
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery;
import org.app.now.domain.process.QQuotation;
import org.app.now.domain.process.Quotation;
import org.app.now.repo.QuotationRepoCustom;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;

public class QuotationRepoImpl implements QuotationRepoCustom {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Quotation> search(String ticketNumber, String description, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
        System.out.println("Searching");
        JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
        QQuotation quotation = QQuotation.quotation;
        query.from(quotation).where(quotation.ticketNumber.like("this")).
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Fechable](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/Fetchable.html) interface.

```
@Override
public List<Quotation> search(String ticketNumber, String description, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
    System.out.println("Searching");
    JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
    QQuotation quotation = QQuotation.quotation;
    return query.from(quotation).where(quotation.ticketNumber.like("this")).fetch();
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
@Override
public List<Quotation> search(String ticketNumber, String description, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
    JPQLQuery<Void> query = new JPAQuery<Void>(em);
    QQuotation quotation = QQuotation.quotation;
    return query.select(quotation)
                .from(quotation)
                .where(quotation.ticketNumber.like("this"))
                .fetch();
}
```